# Check my battery powered layout

Tags: battery-operated, layout, step-up

Few days ago I had topic about issue with power inductor crashing circuit. I almost resolved issue without making new by 90%. However sometimes circuit crashes -> I did some updates based on replies.

Goal: Li-ion battery powered circuit that powers ESP32 & LED strip (total top 1,75A 5V). PCB are splitted into two parts - battery & battery protection circuit / chip & connectors. Part 1 with battery should work, anyway included. Can you give me some advices if I am still wrong? Definitely would like to say with same form factor :)

Components:

- Li-Ion battery
- Protection circuit
- Step-up to 5V 2A ([MT3608](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1811151539_XI-AN-Aerosemi-Tech-MT3608_C84817.pdf), [power inductor](https://cz.farnell.com/multicomp/mcsdrh73b-8r2mhf/inductor-8-2uh-20-2pins/dp/1864474?CMP=i-ddd7-00001003))
- ESP32
- LED strip

**Old layout**
[image]

**Battery scheme** (do you need layout?)
[image]

**Scheme main board**
[image]

**New layout**
[image]